# Should I use Apple payment service

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, payment-gateway

In my app, I have implemented payment service to pay bill to government. All work will be done  by calling web service. My payment web service is also ready.

As I am not doing any sorts of "In app purchase" nor "In app sales", I don't want to involve apple in that. I don't want to user Apple Payment Gateway.

Can I bypass the App Store structure to save 30% of transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The app may not pass the apple review.

Edit: This question will help you
[iPhone app with or without AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531137/iphone-app-with-or-without-appstore/7531250#7531250)

Comment: Consider adding in an excerpt from apples app requirements/approval checklist (whatever that is), to support this statement.

Comment: @Mahmoud Fayez -->> Suppose I will go through Apple Payment Gateway

that means if the user pays his bill standing in queue infront of govt. office then bill will be 30% less than if he will pay for the same bill by iPhone App .

Is this senario happen while paying bill ?